# Constant-time list concatenation in OCaml

Tags: performance, data-structures, linked-list, ocaml

Is it possible to implement constant-time list concatenation in OCaml?

I imagine an approach where we deal directly with memory and concatenate lists by pointing the end of the first list to the beginning of the second list. Essentially, we're creating some type of linked-list like object.

Comment: Do you mean by creating a custom list type or directly on the standard list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the normal list type, no, you can't. The algorithm you gave is exactly the one implemented ... but you still have to actually find the end of the first list...

There are various methods to implement constant time concatenation (see [Okazaki](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) for fancy details). I will just give you names of ocaml libraries that implement it: BatSeq, BatLazyList (both in [batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/)), [sequence](https://github.com/c-cube/sequence/), [gen](https://github.com/c-cube/gen/), [Core.Sequence](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core_kernel/#Sequence).
Pretty sure there is a diff-list implementation somewhere too.

Comment: Can you please a Core_kernel.Sequence here, just for the sake of completeness, https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core_kernel/#Sequence

Answer (score 1):

Lists are already (singly) linked lists. But list nodes are immutable. So you change any node's pointer to point to anything different. In order to concatenate two lists you must therefore copy all the nodes in the first list.